# regex find uppercase character in word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am working on text formatting with regex on a text file. 
I found that

```
\b\w*[А-Ш]{2,}\w*
```

will find all words that are mostly uppercase and does it. 
But how can I find words that have UPPERCASE within the word, but not when its new sentence?

Sample text below:

`ТИКВЕШ – акумулациона ХЦ (дел од повеЌенаменскиот хидросистем) во долниот тек на Црна Река, недалеку од Кавадарци. Првите два агрегата се во погон од 1968, а третиот и четвртиот од 1981 г. ТурбИните се од типот францис. Вкупната инсталирана моЌност изнесува 116 МЊ. Во периодот 1992-2003 г. просечното годиШно проиЗводство изнесувало 135,1 ГЊх, а најголемото 289,9 
ЛИТ: 50 години македонско електрОстопанство, Скопје, 1995; Ј.П. „Електростопанство на Македонија#, Скопје, 1999; Електростопанство на Македонија, годиШен извеШтај, 2003; Др. Р. 
„ТИКВЕШ# (Кавадарци, 30. И ‡ 31. ВИИ 1942) ‡ весник на`

Comment: Is it C#? Python? JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

`(?<!\. |^|\pL)\pL*[А-Я]+\pL*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZLDuNe/4)

`(?<!\. |^|\pL)` is a negative lookbehind. It only matches if your string is not preceded by `.` and a space, or if it is the beginning of the line. I also added a case for `\pL` because for some reason `\b` doesn't seem to work with other languages.

`\pL*` matches 0 or more characters from any language

`[А-Я]+` matches one or more capital cyrillic letters

`\pL*` then of course we match 0 or more characters from any language again

P.S. I'm not really that familiar with the cyrillic alphabet, so let me know if something doesn't look right.